# Server send broadcast event Mobilefirst Platform 8.0?

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

As title I wanna know that does MFP 8.0 support send broadcast event ?

For example : a passenger picked up a trip, he want drivers know about his request. Does MFP 8.0 support simple way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  You can use the Push Notifications functionality.

- In the MFP console, create a tag called "Broadcast".
- In your mobile app's initialization routine, register for that tag (i.e., subscribe to it).
- When the business event happens, use the server-side push notification API to send a notification to the tag "Broadcast". This might be an insert to a "Trips" table in your backend database.
- All devices that subscribe to that tag will get the notification.

-Paul Horan-
IBM